# Laravel site is not working after hosting it HTTP ERROR 500 unable to handle this request

Tags: html, css, mysql, apache, laravel-5

I have developed a laravel app and host it to my private server using WinSCP. But when I hit myurl  it's showing me `The stream or file "/var/www/html/vesMain/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied` and if I set `APP_DEBUG=flas`e then it's showing ``` 500 error``192.168.41.81 is currently unable to handle this request ```. but I I saw the file permission is 644. I don't know why this is happening? Can anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: 1. The IP you post is an internal IP, are you sure you're requesting the correct host? 2. Does every directory all the way to laravel.log have the correct permissions. Also check the ownership of those files match the user for which the PHP process is running.

Comment: @yes it's a private IP. All the folder are 755 and the fils is 644. I couldn't find anything. Even I clear the cache and then upload the files again but it's showing `There is no existing directory at "C:\laragon\www\vesFinal\storage\logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using set the permission 777 to storage folder, logs folder and laravel.log file. Then set permission 777 **view** folder that inside into storage/framework/view and **session**(storage/framework/session) folder. Finally, clear the route and cache.

You can simply run those command.

1. sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/your_app/storage
2. sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/your_app/storage/logs
3. sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/your_app/storage/logs/laravel.log
4. sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/your_app/storage/framework/view
5. sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/your_app/storage/framework/session

Then just clear cache and route

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan route:clear

Answer (score 0):

Giving 777 permission is not at all a good practice. Its like you are giving authority to anyone to change your code. Try 775